# Display automatically set to block in JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a problem in a JavaScript function in which i handle slider properties. I have 3 slide with class `.slide` and everytime i "choose" one of them i set it with `.active-slide` class. The problem is that also if the `display` property of `active-slide` is `table`, when i set this class, it automatically changes to `block` and i can't understand why.
P.s. i'm using also bootstrap.
I'm posting here the part of my code related to this problem:

HTML:

```
<div class="slider">
        <div class="slide active-slide">        
            <div class="container up">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-5 slide-text">
                        <h1 class="slide-title">whatuwant</h1>
                        <p class="slide-par">whatuwant</p>
                        <a href="#" class="slide-link">whatuwant</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-7" id="first-slide-image">
                        <img src="whatuwant"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="slide">        
            <div class="container up">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-5 slide-text"> 
                        <h1 class="slide-title">whatuwant</h1>
                        <p class="slide-par">whatuwant</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-7" id="second-slide-image">
                        <img src="whatuwant"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="slide">        
            <div class="container up">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-5 slide-text">
                        <h1 class="slide-title">whatuwant</h1>
                        <p class="slide-par">whatuwant</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-7 slide-image" id="third-slide-image">
                        <img src="whatuwant"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
    width: 1024px;    
}

.up{  
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;  
    max-width: 1024px;
    max-height: 470px;
}

.row{
    width: 1024px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 1024px;
}

.slider {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 470px;
}

.slide {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.active-slide{
    display: table;   
}
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('.buttonfornextslide').click(function() {
    var currentSlide = $('.active-slide');
    var nextSlide = currentSlide.next();

    if(nextSlide.length === 0) {
      nextSlide = $('.slide').first();
    }

    currentSlide.fadeOut(600).removeClass('active-slide');
    nextSlide.fadeIn(600).addClass('active-slide');
  });


  $('.buttonforpreviousslide').click(function() {
    var currentSlide = $('.active-slide');
    var prevSlide = currentSlide.prev();

    if(prevSlide.length === 0) {
      prevSlide = $('.slide').last();
    }

    currentSlide.fadeOut(600).removeClass('active-slide');
    prevSlide.fadeIn(600).addClass('active-slide');
  });
});
```

I tried to simplify it to the maximum i could.
If the question wasn't clear: how can i hold the `.active-slide` display property to `table`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery automatically assigns "default" styles to elements when using fadeIn, slideDown, etc. Since the default style for divs are "block", that's what is being applied. Instead of using the class "active-slide", try specifically setting the CSS

```
....
prevSlide.fadeIn(600).css('display','table');
```

Refs:

[jQuery bug](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/11303)

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mofle/NZ3eF/3/)  -  you can see that "display" block was in the class' style, and you have to literally add it after the fadeIn function.

In the fiddle, add

```js
.css('display','block');
```

and run it, you'll see the changes